# How can I include images in the description area and a vertical scroll bar on Thickbox (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I would like to get something like this using Thickbox:

[alt text http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/8352/thickbox.png](http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/8352/thickbox.png)

But I'm not sure how to add an image (the golden rose) in the description part (it uses title="description" in the anchor link).

P S: Can I change the color of the description elements?

I would also like to know how to make the scroll bar appear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I never you thickbox. But can't you just use CSS to set a background image on the title element?

..fredrik